# Одно дробное число в два целых

Tags: python, алгоритм

Я реализовал класс `Fraction`, [оригинальный модуль](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) может принять число типа `float` и превратить его в два целых числа, знаменатель и числитель.
Моя версия так не умеет, как такое реализовать, какой алгоритм использовать

Вод код:

```
def NOD(a, b):
    while a and b:
        if a < b:
            b %= a
        else:
            a %= b
    return max(a, b)

def NOK(a, b):
    return a * b / NOD(a, b)


class fraction():
    def __init__(self, x, y = 1):
        self.x, self.y = x, y
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.x} {self.y}"
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        n = NOK(self.y, other.y)
        
        d1, d2 = n / other.y, n / self.y
        
        return fraction(self.x * d1 + other.x * d2, n)
```

Comment: enSO: [How to convert float to fraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355640/how-to-convert-float-to-fraction)

Comment: а math библиотека чем не устроила для НОД и НОК - нужно вообще ничего внешнего не использовать?

Comment: @Zhihar math использовать можно но решил написать сам

Comment: вам тогда надо аккуратнее обработать отрицательные дроби

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ну во-первых можно сделать просто

```
numerator = int(value * 100)
denumerator = 100
```

и потом привести дробь к несократимой

```
gcd = math.gcd(numerator, denumerator);
numenator //= gcd
denumenator //= gcd
```

чем больше точность нужна, тем больше делитель нужен

В c++ я бы просто `float` разобрал бы вытащив мантиссу в виде целого числа и потом бы делил на экспоненту в виде целого числа

А в питоне по идее с их неограниченным `int` можно просто взять `10**n` превышающей размер float (там вроде как двойная точность у питоновских вещественных)

**P.S.**

по идее любое вещественное число можно превратить в непрерывную дробь

[wikipedia](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8C)

и если уж определена операция сложения дробей, то в итоге можно получить и нужную простую дробь наиболее близкую к нужному вещественному числу

этот подход хотя и довольной медленный (несколько операций будет), но наверное и самый точный

Answer (score 3):

Инструкции для точного перевода `float` в дробь:

1. Конвертируйте `float` на точное шестнадцатеричное число в виде строки с применением метода `.hex()`.

   Пример:

   ```
   >>> x = -18.25
   >>> x.hex() 
   '-0x1.2400000000000p+4'
   ```

   Вы получите всегда один и тот же формат, с точкой после целой части, с 13-ми шестнадцатеричными цифрами и экспонентом после буквы `p`.
2. Эта запись значит

   ```
   -(1 + 2/16 + 4/16**2 + ... + 0/16**13) * 2**4
   ```

   или (после приведения к общему знаменателю)

   ```
   -(1*16**13 + 2*16**12 + 4*16**11 + ... + 0) / 16**13 * 2**4
   ```

   или (после умножения дробей)

   ```
   -(1*16**13 + 2*16**12 + 4*16**11 + ... + 0) * 2**4 / 16**13
   ```
3. Теперь ясно, что

   - числителем будет `-(1*16**13 + 2*16**12 + 4*16**11 + ... + 0) * 2**4`,
   - знаменателем будет `16**13` (всегда).

Answer (score 1):

`float`, `int` и ещё некоторые типы имеют метод `as_integer_ratio`, который возвращает кортеж из двух элементов, числителя и знаменателя.

Пример

```
print((15).as_integer_ratio())
print((0.76).as_integer_ratio())
```